# Getting error in AngularJS while concat all JS into a single JS file using GULP task

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am playing around the Angularjs gulp task and when I am concating the all JS file into a single Js file and running the application getting the below error even the application is working fine

"Please DO NOT specify the dropdownSelector option unless you are using jQuery AND Bootstrap.js. Please include jQuery AND Bootstrap.js, or write code to close the dropdown in the on-set-time callback. "

can any one help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make sure that Bootstrap and jQuery are loaded before you are trying to use them in for example an Angular script. I don't know exactly what package you are using to concatenate but it's likely that you are able to specify the order of the files in a configuration file.